# How to Deserialize specific XML document

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

How to deserialize this kind of XML document :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ModelInformation Version="0.9">
<Model>
<Block BlockType="SubSysteme" Name="subSysteme1">
   <p Nom="tag">xx</P>
   <p Nom="coordonee">xx</P>
   <System>
      <p Name="source">xx</P>
      <Block BlockType="Entree" Name="Entree_1">
         <p Name="coordonne"</P>
      </Block> 
      <Block BlockType="Entree" Name="Entree_2">
         <p Name="coordonne">xx</P>
      </Block>
      <Block BlockType="Entree" Name="Sortie_3">
         <p Name="coordonne">xx</P>
      </Block>
      <Block BlockType="SubSysteme" Name="SubSysteme1.01">
         <p Name="tag">xx</P>
         <p Name="coordonne">xx</P>
         <System>
            <p Name="source">xx</P>
            <Block BlockType="Entree" Name="XXX">
               <p Name="coordonne"</P> 
            </Block>
            <Block BlockType="Sortie" Name="XXX">
               <p Name="coordonne">xx</P>
            </Block>
         </System>
      </Block>
   </System>
</Block
</Model>
</ModelInformation>
```

There can be have several systems,subsystems,blocks...

I need to retrieve their attributes names.

First I tried this :

```
public class Block
{
    public Block() { }

    /*[XmlAttribute("BlockType")]
    public String BlockType { get; set; }*/

    [XmlAttribute("Name")]
    public String Name { get; set; }

    [XmlArrayItem("Block")]
    public List<BlockType> BlockTypes = new List<BlockType>();
}
```

and the main :

```
Block block = null;
            using (var stream = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\U503124\Desktop\BstSP_v41_01460_14_01420_v41_0\simulink\blockdiagram.xml"))
            {
                var serialiser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Block));
                subsystem = (Block)serialiser.Deserialize(stream);
                Console.WriteLine(block.Name);

            }
```

block.Name is null, I don't know why.

There are the same tag HTLM inside tag HTLM. How to process?

Comment: In some cases I see `<p Nom="tag">xx</P>` and in others I see `<p Name="source">xx</P>`  Is it really true that sometimes the attribute is named `Nom` and sometimes it is `Name`, or is this a typo in your question?

Answer (score 0):

Your XML is invalid so first thing to do is fix that.

```
<ModelInformation Version="0.9">
   <Model>
      <Block BlockType="SubSysteme" Name="subSysteme1">
         <P Nom="tag">xx</P>
         <P Nom="coordonee">xx</P>
         <System>
            <P Name="source">xx</P>
            <Block BlockType="Entree" Name="Entree_1">
               <P Name="coordonne"></P>
            </Block> 
            <Block BlockType="Entree" Name="Entree_2">
               <P Name="coordonne">xx</P>
            </Block>
            <Block BlockType="Entree" Name="Sortie_3">
               <P Name="coordonne">xx</P>
            </Block>
            <Block BlockType="SubSysteme" Name="SubSysteme1.01">
               <P Name="tag">xx</P>
               <P Name="coordonne">xx</P>
               <System>
                  <P Name="source">xx</P>
                  <Block BlockType="Entree" Name="XXX">
                     <P Name="coordonne"></P> 
                  </Block>
                  <Block BlockType="Sortie" Name="XXX">
                     <P Name="coordonne">xx</P>
                  </Block>
               </System>
            </Block>
         </System>
      </Block>
   </Model>
</ModelInformation>
```

... then you can Paste Special -> Paste XML as class

You get something like this as your class representation. This can be tidied up a lot.

```
[System.Serializable(), System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategory("code"), System.Xml.Serialization.XmlType(AnonymousType = true), System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRoot(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public class ModelInformation
{

    private ModelInformationModel _modelField;

    private decimal _versionField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public ModelInformationModel Model
    {
        get
        {
            return _modelField;
        }
        set
        {
            _modelField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute()]
    public decimal Version
    {
        get
        {
            return _versionField;
        }
        set
        {
            _versionField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Serializable(), System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategory("code"), System.Xml.Serialization.XmlType(AnonymousType = true)]
public class ModelInformationModel
{

    private ModelInformationModelBlock _blockField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public ModelInformationModelBlock Block
    {
        get
        {
            return _blockField;
        }
        set
        {
            _blockField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Serializable(), System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategory("code"), System.Xml.Serialization.XmlType(AnonymousType = true)]
public class ModelInformationModelBlock
{

    private ModelInformationModelBlockP[] _pField;

    private ModelInformationModelBlockSystem _systemField;

    private string _blockTypeField;

    private string _nameField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("P")]
    public ModelInformationModelBlockP[] P
    {
        get
        {
            return _pField;
        }
        set
        {
            _pField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public ModelInformationModelBlockSystem System
    {
        get
        {
            return _systemField;
        }
        set
        {
            _systemField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute()]
    public string BlockType
    {
        get
        {
            return _blockTypeField;
        }
        set
        {
            _blockTypeField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute()]
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _nameField;
        }
        set
        {
            _nameField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Serializable(), System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategory("code"), System.Xml.Serialization.XmlType(AnonymousType = true)]
public class ModelInformationModelBlockP
{

    private string _nomField;

    private string _valueField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute()]
    public string Nom
    {
        get
        {
            return _nomField;
        }
        set
        {
            _nomField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlText()]
    public string Value
    {
        get
        {
            return _valueField;
        }
        set
        {
            _valueField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Serializable(), System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategory("code"), System.Xml.Serialization.XmlType(AnonymousType = true)]
public class ModelInformationModelBlockSystem
{

    private ModelInformationModelBlockSystemP _pField;

    private ModelInformationModelBlockSystemBlock[] _blockField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public ModelInformationModelBlockSystemP P
    {
        get
        {
            return _pField;
        }
        set
        {
            _pField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Block")]
    public ModelInformationModelBlockSystemBlock[] Block
    {
        get
        {
            return _blockField;
        }
        set
        {
            _blockField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Serializable(), System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategory("code"), System.Xml.Serialization.XmlType(AnonymousType = true)]
public class ModelInformationModelBlockSystemP
{

    private string _nameField;

    private string _valueField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute()]
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _nameField;
        }
        set
        {
            _nameField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlText()]
    public string Value
    {
        get
        {
            return _valueField;
        }
        set
        {
            _valueField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Serializable(), System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategory("code"), System.Xml.Serialization.XmlType(AnonymousType = true)]
public class ModelInformationModelBlockSystemBlock
{

    private ModelInformationModelBlockSystemBlockP[] _pField;

    private ModelInformationModelBlockSystemBlockSystem _systemField;

    private string _blockTypeField;

    private string _nameField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("P")]
    public ModelInformationModelBlockSystemBlockP[] P
    {
        get
        {
            return _pField;
        }
        set
        {
            _pField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public ModelInformationModelBlockSystemBlockSystem System
    {
        get
        {
            return _systemField;
        }
        set
        {
            _systemField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute()]
    public string BlockType
    {
        get
        {
            return _blockTypeField;
        }
        set
        {
            _blockTypeField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute()]
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _nameField;
        }
        set
        {
            _nameField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Serializable(), System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategory("code"), System.Xml.Serialization.XmlType(AnonymousType = true)]
public class ModelInformationModelBlockSystemBlockP
{

    private string _nameField;

    private string _valueField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute()]
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _nameField;
        }
        set
        {
            _nameField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlText()]
    public string Value
    {
        get
        {
            return _valueField;
        }
        set
        {
            _valueField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Serializable(), System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategory("code"), System.Xml.Serialization.XmlType(AnonymousType = true)]
public class ModelInformationModelBlockSystemBlockSystem
{

    private ModelInformationModelBlockSystemBlockSystemP _pField;

    private ModelInformationModelBlockSystemBlockSystemBlock[] _blockField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public ModelInformationModelBlockSystemBlockSystemP P
    {
        get
        {
            return _pField;
        }
        set
        {
            _pField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Block")]
    public ModelInformationModelBlockSystemBlockSystemBlock[] Block
    {
        get
        {
            return _blockField;
        }
        set
        {
            _blockField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Serializable(), System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategory("code"), System.Xml.Serialization.XmlType(AnonymousType = true)]
public class ModelInformationModelBlockSystemBlockSystemP
{

    private string _nameField;

    private string _valueField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute()]
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _nameField;
        }
        set
        {
            _nameField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlText()]
    public string Value
    {
        get
        {
            return _valueField;
        }
        set
        {
            _valueField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Serializable(), System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategory("code"), System.Xml.Serialization.XmlType(AnonymousType = true)]
public class ModelInformationModelBlockSystemBlockSystemBlock
{

    private ModelInformationModelBlockSystemBlockSystemBlockP _pField;

    private string _blockTypeField;

    private string _nameField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public ModelInformationModelBlockSystemBlockSystemBlockP P
    {
        get
        {
            return _pField;
        }
        set
        {
            _pField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute()]
    public string BlockType
    {
        get
        {
            return _blockTypeField;
        }
        set
        {
            _blockTypeField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute()]
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _nameField;
        }
        set
        {
            _nameField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Serializable(), System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategory("code"), System.Xml.Serialization.XmlType(AnonymousType = true)]
public class ModelInformationModelBlockSystemBlockSystemBlockP
{

    private string _nameField;

    private string _valueField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute()]
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _nameField;
        }
        set
        {
            _nameField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlText()]
    public string Value
    {
        get
        {
            return _valueField;
        }
        set
        {
            _valueField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Then use your serialise/deserialise.